# How to find the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+x+5)}{\ln(x^8-x+3)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I don't know how to approach this problem:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+x+5)}{\ln(x^8-x+3)}$$

I tried reducing it to the form $\lim (1+x_n)^{1/x_n}=1$, but that didn't work.

Comment: @turkeyhundt With the logarithms, you are incorrect.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 3):

Factoring, we get:

$$x^2+x+5=x^2(1+1/x+5/x^2).$$

Using the above and log rules:

$$\ln(x^2+x+5)=\ln(x^2)+\ln(1+1/x+5/x^2)=2 \ln(x)+\ln(1+1/x+5/x^2).$$

Similarly:

$$\ln(x^8-x+3)=\ln(x^8)+\ln(1/x^7+3/x^8)=8 \ln(x)+\ln(1+1/x^7+3/x^8).$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's as far as I got

Comment: @Ferris Can you see that the second term in the numerator and the second term in the denominator both go to zero?

Comment: Yes, but you can't just say those two are zero and what's left is 2ln(x)/8ln(x).

Comment: @Ferris True. It's not actually a problem here, because the denominator stays away from zero. A straightforward workaround is to divide top and bottom by $\ln(x)$.

Comment: @Ian I think the second option is the only formally correct one: to divide numerator and denominator by $\;\log x\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc Since they're blowing up, I suppose you're right. You can also use L'Hopital's rule, of course, though this is overkill.

Comment: @Ian I thinkl'Hospital can hardly be overkill as it is a very elementary method and the only thing one needs is derivatives. This was my first thought when I read the problem, as we get rid off those annoying logarithms and get a nice, cosy rational function the limit of which is immediate then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step by step solution:

Since both, numerator and denominator of
$$\frac{\ln(x^2+x+5)}{\ln(x^8-x+3)}$$ tend to $\infty$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$, we can apply [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+x+5)}{\ln(x^8-x+3)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x^2+x+5)}{\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x^8-x+3)}\\
> &=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+5}}{\frac{8x^7-1}{x^8-x+3}}\\
> &=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2x+1)(x^8-x+3)}{(x^2+x+5)(8x^7-1)}\\
> &=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2x^9+x^8-2x^2+5x+3}{8x^9+8x^8+40x^7-x^2-x-5}\\
> &=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^7}+\frac{5}{x^8}+\frac{3}{x^9}}{8+\frac{8}{x}+\frac{40}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^7}-\frac{1}{x^8}-\frac{5}{x^9}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> *Note:* Observe, that in the calculation above only the terms with the *highest power of $x$* are relevant for the result.

Comment: Could explain me what does the d and the dx from the beginning mean ? And I don't understand why the other answer's comment propose to divide top and bottom by ln(x).

Comment: @Ferris: The symbol $\frac{d}{dx}$ is the *differential operator*, introduced by Leibniz to denote the *derivative* of a function $f$. So, $f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ with $f=ln$ in our example.

Comment: @Ferris: With regard to your second question: After division by $ln(x^2)$ in numerator and denominator we obtain $\frac{2+\frac{\ln(1+1/x+5/x^2)}{\ln(x^2)}}{8+\frac{\ln(1+1/x^7+3/x^8)}{\ln(x^2)}}$ and we can *see* that $\frac{2}{8}=\frac{1}{4}$ is the resulting limit. But we need to show it in a strict sense, so we can't neglect the ratio of the $ln$ functions and we have even more to apply L'Hôpital's rule. (We could use other techniques like series expansion, but this is presumably not appropriate at this level). Best regards,